# Vaadin table: How to display Boolean as checkboxes with editable=false

Tags: checkbox, boolean, vaadin

I'd like to see checkboxes in the table instead of "true" or "false" text. TableFieldFactory class generates fields only for editable cells. I found only formatProperty where I can return proper unicode character like this ☑, but it doesn't look well. Is there possible to generate own HTML element without creating computed properties?

Answer (score 5):

The generated column approach, replaces the default "toString" with a component:

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("propertyWithBoolean", new Table.ColumnGenerator() {

    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId,
            Object columnId) {
        Boolean checked = (Boolean) source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId).getValue();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setValue(checked);
        // don't allow user to change value
        checkBox.setEnabled(false);
        return checkBox;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the way I dont want to follow. To create computed (generated) property for each boolean column, then make it visible and hide the original. This is very demanding and has the disadvangate, the content is not automaticaly refreshed by valueChange. I needs to be handled by additional listener.

Comment: @Hink "the content is not automaticaly refreshed by valueChange"... you could bind the ItemProperty to the CheckBox

Comment: @Hink, I don't know what you mean by "demanding", but if you use the same property id for the generated column as the original, it is replaced. No need to add an other property and hide the original. And as said by Nexus, if you bind to the property and you actually modify the same property elsewhere, will be automatically updated.  That is though quite rare in real world solutions, so I'd just reset the whole table content (or a specific chekcbox) when you know the data has changed.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to add a style generator to the Table, and solve this via css:

```
  setCellStyleGenerator(new CellStyleGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String getStyle(Table source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
                     if("myBooleanColumn".equals(propertyId){
                        return "true".equals(itemId) ? "checked-checkbox":"unchecked-checkbox";
                     }
                     return null;
            }
        });
```

then define your style:

```
.v-table-cell-content-unchecked-checkbox .v-table-cell-wrapper,
.v-table-cell-content-checked-checkbox .v-table-cell-wrapper{
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.v-table-cell-content-checked-checkbox .v-table-cell-wrapper{      
  background-image: url(".../checked-checkbox.png");
}
.v-table-cell-content-unchecked-checkbox .v-table-cell-wrapper{      
  background-image: url(".../unchecked-checkbox.png");
}
```

If you want the checkbox to be editable you can also set real Vaadin Checkboxes in your column. See [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html) for that.

Comment: or you can use the real checkbox and just disable it

Comment: yep, what ever the designer prefers. In fact you can also change the style of the disabled checkboxes

Comment: Thanks, I found it useful, interesting is the displacement of original text using text-indent :)

Comment: Your're wekcome. I  think this is useful for varios scenarios, also for state-icons for instance

Answer (score 1):

As complement of mstahv answer, a way to refresh checkBox field is using table.refreshRowCache();

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("propertyWithBoolean", new Table.ColumnGenerator() {

@Override
public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId,
        Object columnId) {
    Boolean checked = (Boolean) source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId).getValue();
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setValue(checked);
    // don't allow user to change value
    checkBox.setEnabled(false);
    return checkBox;
}
});
void changeColumnValue(String field, String dato)
{
    item.getItemProperty(field).setValue(dato.equals("true"));
    table.refreshRowCache(); // To refresh the checkbox value in the table
}
```